# NAND circuit from boolean expression

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates, nand

What is the best way to convert following boolean expression to circuit based only on NOT, NAND gates?

[image]

I already done OR, AND circuit.

[image]

But what is the method to receive that?

[image]

Comment: If you are lacking the intuition, then you go with "mechanical" method - that is, replacing each gate with it's NAND-based implementation. Then you can try simplifying it.

Comment: The key here is DeMorgan's Theorem. Using that you can perform an OR function using a NAND gate. Maybe you should ask your instructor to go over it again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewriting a boolean expression only using NAND](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264105/rewriting-a-boolean-expression-only-using-nand)